# XML deserializing and value assignment issue

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I can't seem to figure out the following and I've tried to make as much use of the available topics here.

I have the following document.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root>
  <Data>
    <Package>
      <GWT_></GWT_>
      <ALT_></ALT_>
      <SAT__></SAT__>
    </Package>
    <Package>
      <GWT_></GWT_>    
      <ALT_></ALT_>
      <SAT__></SAT__>
    </Package>
  </Data>
</Root>
```

I wrote classes and a function to deserialize it all.

Classes:

```
[Serializable()]
public class Package
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("GWT_")]
    public string GWT_ { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("ALT_")]
    public string ALT_ { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("SAT__")]
    public string SAT__ { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("Root")]
public class Root
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArray("Data")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItem("Package", typeof(Package))]
    public Package[] Package { get; set; }
}
```

And the function:

```
    private void dataReportToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openData = new OpenFileDialog();
        openData.Filter = "Eta file|Data_*.dat
        if (DialogResult.OK == openData.ShowDialog())
        {
            Package package = null;
            string path = openData.FileName;

            XmlSeriallizerSerializer(typeof(Root));

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
            package = (Root)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.Close();          

        }
    }
```

To start I get the error that it cannot implicitly convert 'Root' to 'Package'.

And I need a way to assign the values that are read (e.g. GWT_"value") to lets say a label.
As you can see there are multiple 'packages' of values, so I need a function to switch back and forward between those packages.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried serialising some (dummy) data to verify that you've got the right attributes to generate the XML? (Heck, it's even worth doing this as a unit test)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me using LinqPAD

```
void Main()
{
    using(var stream = File.Open(@"test.xml", FileMode.Open))
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));

        var root = (Root)serializer.Deserialize(stream);

        root.Dump();
    }
}

public class Package
{
    public string GWT_ { get; set; }
    public string ALT_ { get; set; }
    public string SAT__ { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    [XmlElement("Package")]
    public Package[] Package { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public Data Data{get;set;}
}
```